# Error when searching for a file in C drive in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, search

I want to write a Java program that will search for a specific file in my C:\ drive.

Here's my code:

```
public class Hibernate 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        String directory = "C:\\"; 
        Path start = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(directory);
        Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>(){ 
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException 
            {
                if (file.toString().contains("hiberfil.sys")) 
                {
                    System.out.println(file);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("No such file!");
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem now is that when I run it, it gives me the following error:

```
No such file!
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-20
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsDirectoryStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Unknown Source)
    at Hibernate.main(Hibernate.java:43)
```

However, when I change `String directory = "C:\\";` to `String directory = "F:\\";` (My thumbdrive), it returns me with A LOT A LOT of `No such file!` but no such errors as shown above.

But according to the error: `Hibernate.java:43` should be this: `Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>(){`

How should I solve this? Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: I think you have access restriction on c drive.

Comment: @laksys like how? I'm actually new to java.

Comment: @Steven It's throwing the exception while trying to access $Recycle.Bin, which is a hidden Windows system folder. From what I can tell it can't be accessed normally as it is protected: http://superuser.com/questions/697966/windows-cant-delete-folder-from-recycle-bin-and-it-wont-restore

Comment: @laksys so is there any way that I can remove the restriction? Or is it not possible?

Comment: @Steven see my response below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please override `visitFileFailed` method which is used to skip the inaccessible file.

```
public class Hibernate {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String directory = "c:\\";

        Path start = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(directory);
        Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                    BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {

                if (file.toString().contains("hiberfil.sys")) 
                    System.out.println(file);

                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exp) {
                // System.out.println(file);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    }
}
```